# MySQL foreign key problem rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add foreign keys to my table using the following code:

```
  constraint_name = "fk_#{from_table}_#{to_table}"
  execute %{ 
    CREATE TRIGGER #{constraint_name}_insert 
    BEFORE INSERT ON #{from_table} 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      SELECT 
        RAISE(ABORT, "constraint violation: #{constraint_name}")
      WHERE 
        (SELECT id FROM #{to_table} WHERE 
          id = NEW.#{from_column}) IS NULL
    END
  }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger:  
    CREATE TRIGGER fk_brands_products_insert 
    BEFORE INSERT ON brands 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SELECT 
      RAISE(ABORT, "constraint violation: fk_brands_products")
    FROM brands
    WHERE 
      (SELECT id FROM products WHERE id = NEW.brand_id) IS NULL;
      END;
```

What is wrong with my SQL script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a MySQL Foreign Key constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE #{from_table}
  ADD CONSTRAINT #{constraint_name} FOREIGN KEY
  (#{from_column}) REFERENCES #{to_table}(id)
```

This will constrain from_column on from_table to values in id in #{to_table}.

P.S: If you don't want to name the CONSTRAINT you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE #{from_table}
  ADD FOREIGN KEY
  (#{from_column}) REFERENCES #{to_table}(id)
```

Comment: Yeah I fixed it using that way

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, a trigger is not allowed to return a result set. Even though you are raising a error, MySql doesn't like the `SELECT` statement. Try using a `IF`:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT id FROM #{to_table} WHERE 
          id = NEW.#{from_column}) = 0 THEN
    RAISE(ABORT, "constraint violation: #{constraint_name}");
END IF;
```

Comment: I don't think this is the correct way to set a foreign key in MySQL either....I'm reading through MySQL manual